# Unable to load DLL 'SqlServerSpatial110.dll': Cannot find the specified module

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a wpf c# desktop app that for the last few days has been throwing me this exception when it tries to save data to a sql server database that resides on a dedicated server.
Up until 5 days ago everything was working, and there have been no updates to the app.
The software runs on a Windows 64 bit PC.
Trying to add in the .config file this dependency :

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

did not give any more errors...
Do you have any idea what could be the cause?
Writing to the database is done with the Entity framework but the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types dll is never used.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check in your solution where you're referencing `SqlServerSpatial110.dll`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In my solution don't use the SqlServerSpatial110.dll